# No swear plugin config not working

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to make a no swear plugin, it doesn't error but it is case sensitive even though I am using equalsIgnoreCase. I want it to replace all curse words (As defined in a config) with the word "curse" if there are more than 10 recipients of the message. Why isn't this code working?

Main plugin code:

```
public class main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener  {
    public static Bukkit plugin;
       public void onEnable()
    {
      Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
      getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
      saveConfig();
      this.reloadConfig();
      Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Enabled!");
    }

    public void onDisable()
    {
      getLogger();
      Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Disabled!");
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void playerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
        Set r = e.getRecipients();
        if (r.size() > 10 ) {
           List g = this.getConfig().getList("Swears");
           for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++) {
              if(g.get(i).tostring().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getMessage())) {
                  String message = e.getMessage().replaceAll(g.get(i).toString(), "curse");
                  e.setMessage(message);
              }
          }
    }
}
}
```

config.yml:

```
#Default Config
Swears:
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: NoSwear
main: me.mrpoopy345.bukkitplugin.main
version: 1.0
author: mrpoopy345
description: NoSwear

commands:
```

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would change things:

```
//By convention you always capitalize Class names.  So I changed the name from "main" to "Main".
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    // I am not sure why you had a static Bukkit variable, so I removed it.

    // This variable is transient, so it can be safely accessed from other threads
    public transient List<String> swares;

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        this.reloadConfig();

        // I get the swears out of the config here, so I won't have to
        // access the config while in the AsyncPlayerChatEvent
        swares = getConfig().getStringList("Swears");


        // A more common way to log something is through the logger, here is an example:
        getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Enabled!");
        // Also, a good thing to remember is the the console will not see chat colors as their code
        // So instead of displaying a message as red it would display '§4message'
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        //Here is a different way to use the logger:
        getLogger().info("Disabled!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

        // I combined this to one line, and reversed it so there are less curly braces.
        if (e.getRecipients().size() > 10)
            return;

        // I replaced what you did with this, it's much simpler!
        for (String sware : swares) {
            // adding (?i) tells it to ignore case
            e.setMessage(e.getMessage().replaceAll("(?i)" + sware, "curse"));
        }
    }
}
```

Because I changed the plugin class name, you will also need to change the plugin.yml main to `me.mrpoopy345.bukkitplugin.Main`

Cheers!

(I don't think this syncs the chat event to the main thread, but if it does someone edit my post and fix it)